# Display image from link in JSON

Tags: html, angular

I'm currently working with a `json` dataset that has an image link field, how can I display this image in my angular application? I have a folder containing the images in my application but have been unable to get the images to display, the images folder is located in the src directory of the application but I'm unsure if this is the best place to store it.

[image: an example of the image link in the dataset]

This was my attempt at displaying the image, i tried the same approach as getting the data (country, release year, language etc.) from the dataset but this did not work.

```html
<div class="card-body">
  {{book.imageLink}}
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  Country of Origin: {{book.country}} <br>
  Year Released: {{book.year}} <br>
  Language: {{book.language}} <br>
  Pages: {{book.pages}}
</div>
```

Also some of the data was not retrieved from the dataset such as year and pages which I'm rather confused about. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any code for how "book" is being filled?

Comment: Your images should be in the assets/ folder not in src.

Answer (score 1):

You need an img tag to display the image, Bind the `src` to the image link

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <img [src]="book.imageLink" />
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  Country of Origin: {{book.country}} <br />
  Year Released: {{book.year}} <br />
  Language: {{book?.language}} <br />
  Pages: {{book?.pages}}
</div>
```

Use Safe navigation operator (`?.`) if some properties are empty.
StackBlits [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-65551709?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Ive corrected the code and moved the images folder but the image still wont display, the country of origin and pages will also not display even though none of the fields are empty in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by updating the imageLink in the json file by adding "/../../../assets/" to the image path.

[image]

Comment: Nop, imageLink must be `/assets/images/hings-fall-apart.jpg`. See that you starts from "/assets". Angular "copy" your folder assets to the folder where the index.html is (*). If you use `ng build --prod` you can see it. (*) really if you change the `<base href="/">` in your index.html Angular look for this "base".

Answer (score -1):

try this code:
may be it will help you.

```
 <div class="card-body">
  <img src="{{book.imageLink}}">
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  Country of Origin: {{book.country}} <br>
  Year Released: {{book.year}} <br>
  Language: {{book.language}} <br>
  Pages: {{book.pages}}
</div>
```

Comment: src should be a property binding instead of interpolation.